# EF Code First Connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm struggling to find a solution to the issue I'm having connecting to my SQL Server running on my home network. It normally works fine, i have other projects using EF that work correctly where I'm using an EDMX model. The SQL Authentication details im passing work fine to connect to the server.

I'm using the following connection string in my App.Config file :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Server=192.168.1.4\SQLDEV01;Database=TestLab;user id=Kaiser;password=mud.sit.map-651;Integrated Security=True;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The Exception thrown is :-

{"The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string."}

And its inner exception >

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
>   with Windows authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Windows Authentication when you are specifying `Trusted_Connection=true`, so it's trying to login with the identity attached to the thread of whatever type of application you are running.

If you are using sql authentication, remove the `Trusted_Connection` property from your connection string.